# Finding an oriented path for line integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $\mathbf{F}(x,y)=\langle 3y,x-1 \rangle$. Find an oriented path $C$ from $(2,2)$ to $(1,1)$ such that $\int_C \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}=4$

Is there a general way to do this beyond trial and error? I can't see one.

I also know that $\int_{C}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}=4$ where $C$ is the line segment starting at $(1,1)$ and ending at $(2,2)$.

Comment: Hint: suppose you make two different 'guesses' for $C$. What does Green's theorem tell you about how different they'll be?

Comment: @Semiclassical aah that answered the question for me. Great hint. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose you make two different guesses for $C$. What does [Green's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_theorem) tell you about how different their line integrals will be? (See the spoiler block below for the full answer.)

---

> To start with, let's make some convenient guesses to get a handle on what kind of answers we get. Each path is piecewise-linear, and as the computations are obvious I'll just state the results: 
>  
> \begin{align} C_1:&(1,1)\to (1,2)\to (2,2)& \implies\int_{C_1}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}=6\\ C_2:&(1,1)\to (2,2)&\implies \int_{C_2}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}=5\\ C_3:&(1,1)\to (2,1 )\to (2,2)&\implies \int_{C_3}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}=4\end{align} 
>  
> So in this case it's easy to stumble upon a contour that'll give the right answer. But let's suppose for a moment we didn't bother to do this guess; could we have *predicted* that it would give the correct integral? To do so, we first recall why different paths give different results. Note that the curl of $\mathbf{F}$ is given as $\nabla\times\mathbf{F}=-2\hat{z}$; consequently $\mathbf{F}$ is not the gradient of a scalar function, and so we do not have path-independence. 
>  
>
> The difference in paths, then, is just an area integral over by $(\nabla\times \mathbf{F})_z$. But we saw above that this was just $-2$, so the difference in paths is just $-2 A(D)$. This was in fact visible in the calculations earlier: Both $C_2-C_1$ and $C_3-C_2$ enclose oriented areas of $+1/2$, and so the line integrals differ by $1$. 
>  
>
> Thus we could have deduced $C_1$ would work from calculating either $C_2$ or $C_3$. And we can in fact do better: If we pick any curve $C$ from $(1,1)$ to $(2,2)$ such that $C-C_1$ has zero oriented area (i.e. same area enclosed clockwise as anti-clockwise) then we are guaranteed to have $\int_{C}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}=\int_{C_3} \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}=4.$ So there are infinitely many curves that give the desired answer, with $C_3$ just being the most convenient.